# Grouping and colouring each grouping in excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel

can you tell me how I can group rows using a value in a specific cell and then highlight the individual groups by alternate colours i.e. one group with white background and one group with a colour in excel? I have macro code which inserts a blank line but I don't know how to colour using macro.

Comment: [GOOGLE "change row color vba"](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=change%20row%20color%20vba) Then cycle through the colors.

Comment: I've tried the facility offered by DATA but this adds a total which I don't want. I just want to group the rows by a specific column and highlight alternate rows is possible. Adding in a blank row was another of grouping using VBA but as I am not a coder I couldn't amend to change colour.

Comment: Heres the VBA I am using if it helps : Sub AddBlankRows()
'
Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer
Dim oRng As Range

Set oRng = Range("AN2")

iRow = oRng.Row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do
'
If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
    Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    iRow = iRow + 2
Else
    iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""
'
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a macro, just run conditional formatting for values equal to the value of the group you are using.

[Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/) is an excellent guide for how to highlight a row using conditional formatting. It does exactly what you asked for without having to write any code. As you can see it works for multiple rows sharing the common set value.

This is assuming that the only reason you wanted them grouped in the first place was for colouring them together, this method is best if you want to preserve the order of your data.